# How to prove spaces are homeomorphic using normalisation method?

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the punctured plane, $X= \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, is homeomorphic to the complement of the unit disc, $Z=\{\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \  \|\underline{x}  \| > 1\}=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D^2$ where $D^2=\{\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid \ \|\underline{x}\|\leq1\}$ and $\underline{x}=(x_1,x_2)$

We need to prove that there is a continuous inverse that has a continuous inverse. So I can see that we may define a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}\to Z$ by increasing the length of each vector by $1$. 
i.e.  $f(\underline{x})=(\underline{x}+1)$ but then this doesn't give the required result. In fact, we need to normalise the vector giving $f(\underline{x})=(\underline{x}+1)\frac{\underline{x}}{\| \underline{x} \|}$  and I don't understand why or how this works. Similarly with the inverse.

Comment: What is $x+1$? The real number $1$ isn't a $2$-vector

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\left\| \frac{1}{\|x\|}x\right\|=1$ and so $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is a vector of unit length in the direction of $x$, so $f(x)=x+\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is the vector you get by moving $x$ a unit length away from for the origin along the line which passes through both $x$ and the origin. It's easy to see by construction then that $\|f(x)\|=\|x\|+1.$